# Points of non-derivability of the conjugate $u^*$ of a convex function.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, continuity

Let be $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(-\infty,+\infty]$ a proper and convex function.

The conjugate function of $u$ is a function $u^*:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(-\infty,+\infty]$, defined by $$ u^*(y):={\rm sup}\{ (x,y)-u(x)\; |\; x\in\mathbb{R} \}, \,\ {\rm for} \;y\in\mathbb{R}.$$

So $u^*$ is convex.

I know that, if $u$ is also a closed function (i.e. its epigraph is a closed set), then $$y\in\partial u(x)\quad{\rm iff}\quad x\in\partial u^*(y),$$ 
where $\partial u(x)$ is the sub differential of $u$ in $x$.

I was wondering if there is a relation between the points of non derivability of $u$ and of $u^*$. Can I say something about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $u(x)=\max(0, |x|-1)^2$ is differentiable everywhere, with the derivative
$$u'(x) = \begin{cases} 2(x+1), \quad & x<-1 \\ 0, & -1\le x\le 1 \\  2(x-1), & x>1\end{cases}$$
Accordingly, its conjugate $u^*$ has the derivative equal to the inverse of $u'$:
$$(u^*)'(y) = \begin{cases} y/2-1, \quad & y<0 \\ y/2+1 , & y>0\end{cases}$$  This leads to 
$$
u^*(y) = \frac{y^2}{4}+|y|,\quad y\in\mathbb{R}
$$
being non-differentiable at $0$.

So, the relation is not between non-differentiability points of $u$ and $u^*$, but rather between "flat spots" of $u$ and non-differentiability  points of $u^*$. This is particularly clear in one dimension, where the derivative of a convex function is an increasing function. The discontinuities of the inverse of an increasing function $f$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the intervals  where $f$ is constant.